# JDBC insert query with conditions using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I have to write JDBC insert query based on the below conditions:

The package must not be present in the table based on the following key:
The package must not have a  of 'D'
The Package must have one of the following kickout status (AK, BK, GK, CK, QK)
The Resolve Match Flag (RESOLVE_MATCH_FLAG) in ACT001F the must not be Y or is NULL
The stop id/type must not have a resolve in the Kickout_Resolve file as indicated by the absence of the stop in the original stop field of the table altogether or if the stop is in the table the absence of a resolved stop for the record.
The stop id/type must not be present in KICKOUT_CORRECTIONS_DETAIL  table as indicated by the delivery stop id and type matching an original stop id and type and the Estimated Facility Date in the  file = the Deliver date from the Active Package feed and the presence of the tracking id.

I have written the below query but needed to add the conditions, can anybody help me on the same.

```
INSERT INTO FXG_VCAPI_SCHEMA.KICK_OUT_STATUS
(TRAK_ID, PCKUP_SQ_ID,VINTAGE,EFD,STOP_ID,STOP_ID_TP,KICKOUT_STAT,KICKOUT_ST,BEGIN_PCKUP_TM, END_PCKUP_TM, CNFRM_NBR, PCKUP_TP, CO_NM, CONT_NM, PRIM_ADR, SCNDY_ADR, CITY, STATE, PSTL_CD, HOUSE_NM, STR_NM, CNTRY_CD, HIGH_RISE_IND, GEOCODE_VNDR, GEOCODE_LAT, GEOCODE_LON, GEOCODE_SCR, VALID_GEOCODE_IND, ZIP_CONF_SCR, VALID_ADDR_IND, FAC_NM, NTWK_CD, KICKOUT_TP, CREATED_DT, UPDATED_DT)
VALUES ('2070881', '119052302274900001', '201306',SYSDATE,'500000001444168', 'I','AK', 'A','GK', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, '', '', '',SYSDATE,SYSDATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

:)

I think you could take a look at a lot of SQL verifications. It'll make sure to always have data matching your expectations rather than doing all the verification in java.

the **SQL CHECK** statement for instance. It let you create custom rules for your tables, throwing an SQL Exception if the datas you try to insert don't match your rules. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

the columns like KICKOUT_ST could be an **ENUM** with values ('AK', 'BK', 'GK', 'CK', 'QK') forcing these values specifically https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerator-enum-in-mysql/

For the few columns that should not be null, make sure to apply the NOT NULL statement. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_not_null.asp

I don't know if there's consistent way to make these verifications in Java / JDBC. Maybe could you find it using Hibernate, JPA and/or Spring Data but If you really want to make sure the input data match your model in java you'll have to make the checks manually (in addition to the SQL validation) :)